# Remove the range of lines from file using shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

My test file test.txt is given below:

```
destination mailerr  { file("/var/log/mail.err" fsync(yes)); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mailerr);  destination(mailerr); };

#
# and also all in one file:
#
destination mail { file("/var/log/mail"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_mail); destination(mail); };

destination mailwarn { file("/var/log/mail.warn"); };
log 
{ 
#source(src); 
filter(f_mailwarn); destination(mailwarn); };
```

I want to remove below lines using shell script

```
log 
{ 
#source(src); 
filter(f_mailwarn); destination(mailwarn); };
```

This lines might be comes different structure like

```
log{ source(src); filter(f_mailwarn); destination(mailwarn); };
                          (or)
log
{ 
source(src); 
filter(f_mailwarn); 
destination(mailwarn); 
};
                           (or)
log
{ source(src); filter(f_mailwarn); destination(mailwarn); };
                           (or)
#   log { source(src); filter(f_mailwarn); destination(mailwarn); };
};
```

These are the possibilities. I am using sed command:

```
sed '/log/{:a;/destination(mailwarn);.*}/d;N;ba}' test.txt
```

But it'll remove all line because first line it self "log" comes. So many of "log" comes in this file so how to remove the particular lines using shell script.

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification. Are you just trying to remove lines from a file based on a list of lines to remove, are you trying to remove the entire `log` function, or are you trying to do something else that I'm not understanding?

Comment: @Jeffrey Cash i want to remove log function which contain "destination(mailwarn);"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed  '/^[# ]*log/{:loop; /destination(.*}/d; /}/{n}; N; b loop;}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `/^[# ]*log/` - Starts to process the block `{}` when `regex` matches.
- `/destination(.*}/d` - Deletes the pattern space when `regex` matches. Starts a new cycle.
- `/}/{n}` - When it finds `}`, then prints pattern space and reads next line of input. (for printing out an non `log...destination()` line.
- `N` - This appends next line input to pattern space.
- `b loop` - This transfers flow control to `loop`.

Comment: Can you add in it a bit of explanation? really want to understand this and upvote it :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It removes all `log` functions, not just ones with `destination(mailwarn)`

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too big, use the `-z` option to process entire file in one shot (@[SLePort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344961/sleport) notes that this is a GNU specific option)

```
sed -z 's/log[ \t\n]*{[^}]*destination(mailwarn);[ \t\n]*};//g' test.txt
```

- `log` start of match
- `[ \t\n]*{` zero or more non space/tab/newline characters followed by `{`

  - to avoid false matching `log/mail.warn"); };` if `[^{]*{` was used instead
- `[^}]*` zero or more non `}` characters
- `destination(mailwarn);` string to match
- `[ \t\n]*};` zero or more non space/tab/newline characters followed by `};`
- the matched pattern gets deleted as replacement string is empty

Similar with `perl`

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/log\s*\{[^}]*destination\(mailwarn\);\s*};//g' test.txt
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `-z` is a GNU sed flag.

Comment: Good use of GNU feature of `sed` ++

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed '/^#*[[:blank:]]*log/{:a;/};/!{N;ba;s/\n//;};/destination(mailwarn)/d;}' file
```

Adds lines from `log` up to `};` to the pattern space, search in it for  `destination(mailwarn)` and if found, deletes lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my somewhat janky way of getting the job done. It seems to work in all the cases you posted, but is in no way a universal solution to this problem.

`tr '\n' '\0' < test.txt | sed 's/log[^{}]*{[^}]*destination(mailwarn);[^}]*};//g' | tr '\0' '\n'`

If `test.txt` contains null characters, it may not work properly. This command essentially looks for `log` followed by a `{` at some point, then until a `}` is reached `destination(mailwarn);`, eventually followed by `};`, and deletes this match if found.

I hope someone else posts a more robust solution to this problem, but this is the only quick solution I was able to come up with.